# radio button value not getting in controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am getting Json responce through API.

```
var json =  [{"Price":70},{"Price":100}];
```

I am showing this data on View

```
<form name="InfoForm" novalidate > 
<div class="list" ng-repeat="data in json" > 
<ion-radio ng-value="data.Price" ng-model="test.Price">{{data.Price}}</ion-radio>
</div>
<button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="goDetail(test)">Next</button>
</form>

Controller : 

$scope.goDetail = function(data){
     alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

But click on button I am not getting the selected radio button value in controller.its showing undefined.

Comment: replace data.Price with test.Price and try

Comment: No, its not working @Amin

Comment: my bad. replace test.Price with data.Price and make sure your controller can access the json. If you haven't defined it in the controller (which I don't see), make sure you inject it in the controller.

Comment: I am able to see the data in View. replacing test.Price with data.Price is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="InfoForm" novalidate > 
    <div class="list" ng-repeat="data in json" > 
        <ion-radio name="price" ng-value="data.Price" ng-model="result.selected">{{dataPackage.PackagePrice}}</ion-radio>
    </div>
    <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="goDetail(result.selected)">Next</button>
</form>
```

In the above code `ng-model` is `result.selected`. So, make sure you have an object called `result` specified on scope. like so: `$scope.result = {selected: ''}`. This will then bind result to that object.

In your example, you're binding to `test.Price` and I'm not sure if you have the model `test` initialised on scope.

P.S. If you want the radio buttons to be mutually exclusive, make sure you add `name` attribute to the radio button. Example:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" ng-value="dataPackage.PackagePrice" ng-model="data.selected">{{dataPackage.PackagePrice}}
```

Comment: @VishalSingh, Have a look at the difference between your `<ion-radio>` and this:

`<ion-radio ng-value="data.Price" ng-model="data.Price">{{dataPackage.PackagePrice}}</ion-radio>`

Comment: ok let me clear. if i am using simple radio input for this like
<input type="radio" ng-value="data.Price" ng-model="data.Price">{{data.Price}} same problem i am facing.

Comment: How about you create a jsFiddle or plunker with the code and lets see if that can be fixed

Comment: From this only I am getting one value..not able to get multiple input select value..

Comment: Yeah, that's right, that's how it's implemented. If you're after getting multiple values selected, maybe checkboxes are the way to go instead of radio buttons. Maybe have a look at this library: http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/